# Авторизация на сайте и открытие указанной страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Смотрите, у меня есть форма:

```
<form action="site.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="login" />
    <input type="password" name="user_pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, в случае верного ввода пароля, с моего сайта идет переход на сайт, на котором проходила авторизация.

Далее идет код:

```
<div class="left_menu">
<a href="index.html" class="active_left_menu">НАЧАТЬ</a>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Начать" сайт проходил авторизацию и открывал не страницу, где он авторизовывался, а страницу, которую мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если форма на вашем сайте, максимум что вы можете - указать в action адрес какой-то страницы которая изначальным владельцем должна быть настроена чтобы получать такие запросы с конкретно вашего сайта.